# Is there an OSGi-ready version of the guava sources (for use in Eclipse)?

Tags: java, osgi, guava

Whenever a new google guava version is released, I manually create an OSGi guava source bundle for use in our projects (to be able to see the guava sources within Eclipse).

I wonder if there is a download site where such an source bundle is already available (the Eclipse orbit download is a few versions behind...)?

Best regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Orbit](http://eclipse.org/orbit/): The latest release includes org.goole.guava version 10.0.1, 11.0.2 and 12.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I said: the orbit version is 12 the current guava version is 14.0.1. It would be convenient to have a OSGi source bundle whenever a release is made available.

Comment: Just about everybody would agree with this. There are a new project in the Eclipse - Eclipse Bundle Recipes - that will hopefully ease this work in the future.